# Null object reference - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.db.j()'

Tags: android, kotlin

I noticed some of my users are getting this exception. I don't know how to reproduce it, I only have the reports on Crashlytics.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.db.j()' on a null object reference
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cx.onClick(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815061@21.48.15 (100300-0):3)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
   at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
   at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: I have the same report. As far as reproduction it happens when you select a pin on the map and tap the "Navigate" button that appears in the lower right side. Why - I still have no idea...